# Restore rules with iptables-restore ignoring errors

Tags: linux, iptables

I would like to know if it's possible ignore the errors in the restoring procedure.

I have in my rules lot of lines like:

```
-A mychain -s somehost.com -j DROP
```

My rules comes from dynamic lists and it could happen that if somehost.com is temporarly offline, not routable or something like that iptables-restore refuses to restore the rules and throws out errors like:

```
iptables-restore v1.6.0: host/network 'somehost.com' not found
Error occurred at line: 342
Try 'iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

Well I would like that `iptables` could just ignore the `somehost.com` line if the host is not reachable.

Can this being done adding some flags to `iptables-restore`?

Comment: `iptables` does not care whether a host is reachable just whether the name can be resolved to an IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use DNS name in iptables rules but **it is not a best practice** for more reasons. And the major reason - iptables performs resolving once during rules loading. In future DNS name may be changed and your host will not know it.

As you could know iptables need only **successfull DNS name resolving**. So if DNS name does not exist rules loading ends with errors.

You may create script and check name resolving inside of it:

```
#!/bin/bash

host_check=$( dig -t A somehost.com +short 2>/dev/null | wc -l )

if (( $host_check > 0 ))
        then sed -i '/.*somehost\.com/s/^#//' file
        else sed -i 's/.*somehost\.com/#&/' file
fi
```

this script check name resolving. If name are resolved (output will be one or more lines) script delete comments in each lines with certain DNS name. If not - scipt add comments to each line with DNS name.

`file` - this is iptables script from `iptables-save > file` command

After this checks you can load rules with `iptables-restore < file`

---

I strongly recommend to not using this approach. **You need to find a way to refuse of DNS names in iptables rules.**